# Sign or decrypt document with user ID

Tags: xpages

XPages can use Notes Java API for sign/encrypt document, some examples here:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/NotesDocument_sample_JavaScript_code_for_XPages#sign

Unfortunately, all is done by server identity - in above example the document is signed by server ID (in case of XPiNC it is user's ID) so server is able to encrypt document (uses public key of user specified in PublicEncryptionKeys field). But the problem is to sign or decrypt document (private keys is required). Initializing datasource with encrypted document fails.

There is possibility to use LotusScript agent with Notes C API calls to invoke sign/decrypt methods, but API requires Notes ID file available on filesystem and user's password for that ID (as string).

I am looking for advice, how to securely sign or decrypt document (based on IDs stored in user's mail files for example).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in one of my XPages applications. Did you find a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: In short: no. There is a chance to use ID vault in combination with API mentioned by @stwissel, but development is troublesome.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In case I manage to solve this issue, I'll post the code here.

Answer (score 1):

Open a PMR with IBM. This is a sticky point for a long time. You could get away with sign/encrypt if your users have the id inside of their mail file as part of iNotes.

**Update**
Long answer:

Since version 7.0 there are [encryption functions](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/7.0/api70ug.nsf/85255d56004d2bfd85255b1800631684/85255d56004d2bfd85255cf1006b33f4?OpenDocument) in the C-API that don't rely on the *current* id file, but on properly provided credentials. A developerworks [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/nd7-security-api/) explains that in detail. You could use these calls and the Notes.id inside the iNotes database (if the mail files sits on the same server) and achieve encryption/decryption. Probably subclassing the DominoDocument would be the least stressful approach. Or you get every customer you can lay hands on to open a PMR on this.

Comment: I don't think this is an option. As a IBM business partner we can not open PMR - only customers can. And we can not deliver any solution (to any customer) which lacks essential functions (sign/encrypt). Draw game.

Comment: get every customer you have to open one

Comment: thanks for update and links. what bothers me: in that article, part "Using the attached ID to read encrypted messages", step 1 - "Detach the user's ID file from the mail file by using the method SECExtractIdFileFromDB". That means there are user's ID files on server filesystem what I see as security hole. It also requires user's password, which must be securely transferred to server - how? some say SSL is sufficient, but I doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Frantisek , not an answer - I couldn't see where to comment - just adding to you conversation with Stephan. I can relate to your dillema re pre-sales PMRs but you do have some options.

You are correct about the PMR but you can raise a help desk query with IBM and in my experience the response has been very helpful.

Also you probably are an IBM customer in that you may have the "value pack" or perhaps an express licence to allow you to access your server.

try http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Open_service_request/Software/Lotus/Lotus_brand_support_(general)

The other option is to register with the Virtual Innovation Centre as they can provide some support but the direct route above is better if you can find your user ID
https://www-304.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/ContentHandler/isv_com_tsp_vic_overview